# Yii default rule не работает

Tags: php, yii2

Создал модель примерно следующего содержания:

```
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }


    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username', 'auth_key', 'password', 'password_reset_token', 'status', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'required'],
            [['status', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
            [['username', 'fullname', 'password', 'password_reset_token', 'email'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['auth_key'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
            [['username'], 'unique'],

            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['created_at', 'default', 'value' => 123],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
            ['status', 'filter', 'filter' => 'intval'],
        ];
    }

    //... дальше идут функции
}
```

Теперь в контроллере делаю так:

```
$user = new User();
$user->username = 'admin';
$user->email = 'admin';
$user->setPassword('admin');
$user->generateAuthKey();
if ($user->validate()) {
     $user->save();
} else {
     return var_dump($user->errors);
}
```

И в результате получаю ошибку:

```
array(4) {
    ["password_reset_token"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(53) "Password Reset Token cannot be blank."
    }
    ["status"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(29) "Status cannot be blank."
    }
    ["created_at"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(56) "Created At cannot be blank."
    }
    ["updated_at"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(60) "Updated At cannot be blank."
    }
}
```

Вопрос - почему дефолтное значение, указанное в модели для `created_at` и `status` не применилось? Как правильно указать дефолтное значение для атрибутов?

```
['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
['created_at', 'default', 'value' => 123],
```

Comment: Так вы выньте данные поля из обязательных. Зачем они вам в required? А При создании объекта через new он ни чем не заполняется. Т.к. new - это не ключевое слово фреймворка

Comment: А вот при save в БД всё прилетит как надо

Comment: Вот тут обсуждаем: https://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=66434&p=275329   всё печально на мой взгляд))) решения есть, но они, на мой взгляд костыльные....... проще всего сделать базовую модель отнаследованную от AR, там в методе `init` прописать логику, чтобы при создании модель заполнялась дефолтными значениями и уже от этой базовой модели всех наследовать